# How to make a gradient scatter plot

Tags: python, plot, gradient, scatter

I want a scatter plot with a gradient color similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXQcn.png) and I'm struggling to find info about how to do it, can you help me?

For example I have X and Y like this:

```
n = 1024
X = np.random.normal(0,1,n)
Y = np.random.normal(0,1,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into matplotlib :

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize = (12.8, 6))
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.title('blabla')

n = 1024
X = np.random.normal(0,1,n)
Y = np.random.normal(0,1,n)

plt.plot(X, Y, 'ro')
plt.savefig('./toto.png')
```

Not certain regarding gradients, though they do quite a lot of stuff:

https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html